# Create a patch from a multiple revisions in TortoiseSVN using a commandline

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, patch

I tried to create a patch by using TortoiseSVN -> Create Patch.. but it only allows me to retrieve one of the most recent revision.

I know that there is a way to create a patch from a set of revisions using a commandline. How do we do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Show log, select the revisions (including one more previous revision), right-click, choose "show unified diff".
Then save that diff.

Check which revisions are compared in the generated patch file.

Comment: What about diff for several revisions that go not one by one?